# read a well defined frame with qtserialport

Tags: qt

I'm developing a desktop application with  qt  which communicates with stm32 to send and receive data.
The thing is, the data to transfer, follow a well-defined shape, with a previously defined fields. My problem is that I can't find how read () or readall()  work or how Qserialport even treats the data. So my question is how can I read data (in real time, whenever there is data in the buffer) and analyze it field by field (or per byte) in order to be displayed in the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing to it. `read()` and `readAll()` give you bytes, optionally wrapped in a `QByteArray`. How you deal with those bytes is up to you. The serial port doesn't "treat" or interpret the data in any way.

The major point of confusion is that somehow people think of a serial port as if it was a packet oriented interface. It's not. When the `readyRead()` signal fires, all that you're guaranteed is that there's at least one new byte available to read. You must cope with such fragmentation.